# End to end test with serenity-js , cumber ,protractor and jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, cucumberjs, serenity-js

I am new to serenity-js and trying to implement it for end to end test case for an angular application.

My team has already written the unit test case using jasmine. As I know, serenity-js don't support jasmine. what should I do to make it work?

Option 1: install both jasmine and mocha/chai

option 2: install 2.0.1-alpha.4 Please suggest

Comment: Protractor+Jasmine for UI e2e automated tests worked super well for us; you can build a really complex E2E framework with just those 2 tools

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `expect` from Jasmine and have already invested significant effort in writing tests with it, the [expect NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect) from Jest is very similar to Jasmine's and is compatible with CucumberJS. Live Demonstration: https://testjam.io/?p=D11o5cwOIQukGy1F6GRU

Otherwise, I'd recommend using Chai.